# How to Add Foreign key (FK) on Legacy database that has no FK but only Query join

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have an old database that is live in production, and this database does not have a Foreign key and without documentation.
The relation between tables is done directly in stored procedure using query with inner join.

the question is
how do I add Foreign key in the tables that has relations in this database.
I hope I don't have to analyze one by one stored procedures to get these table relationship. and I don't know the sequence of store procedures that need to be analyzed

Please advise.
thank you

this time I analyze stored procedures and record the relationships between the tabs but this method is frustrating.

I look for other ways to get relationships between tables other than analyzing one by one stored procedures.

Comment: The only way a `relationship` can be determined between 2 tables is by `Foreign Keys` So if you dont have any `Foreign Keys` your only way is analysing the schema's. In any case I think that any database without `Foreign Keys` is an accident waiting to happen. Probably the data in there is already corrupt